# Mod_ReWrite: Unwanted redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess, Clean URL, unwanted 301 redirect, 1AND1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224419/htaccess-clean-url-unwanted-301-redirect-1and1)

Mod_Rewrite is redirecting.

```
RewriteRule ^viewPage/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /viewPage?ID=$1&Title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Typing in

> www.domain/viewPage/123/abc/

is returning back

> www.domain/viewPage.php?ID=123&Title=abc

I don't want the page to redirect from `www.domain/viewPage/123/abc/` to `www.domain/viewPage.php?ID=123&Title=abc`.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Your missing the `.php` at the end of viewPage, mod_rewrite will be matched again if its missing also the matches seem abit restrictive.

```
RewriteRule ^viewPage/(.*)/(.*)/$ viewPage.php?ID=$1&Title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Wow. Nice catch. I was staring at the question for ever and didn't see the missing `.php`. Sneaky little error.

Comment: Hi, my mistake. I've copied the above example incorrectly. My htaccess reads: ^viewPage/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /viewPage.php?ID=$1&Title=$2 [NC,L]. I still have the problem of it redirecting. Could it be something to do with cache?

Comment: @user1058903 Ive updated my answer also a url like `www.domain/viewPage/123/abc/` will match but `www.domain/viewPage/123/abc` will not.

Comment: I agree. The thing is when I type www.domain/viewPage/123/abc/ I can see the the http status code response was 301 and the location response was www.domain/viewPage.php?ID=123&Title=abc. The URL in the browser changes to www.domain/viewPage.php?ID=123&Title=abc. I don't think it's a Mod_ReWrite issue as it seems to be interpreting the CLEAN url. The problem is that it is redirecting and I don't want it to.